# Resampling 13 arc second DEM to 1/3 arc second

Tags: dem

I need to download DEMs for almost half of the U.S. but not all the locations have 1/3 arc second DEMs but the have 13 arc second. Can anyone help me how to resample 13 arc second DEM to 1/3 arc second?

Comment: You are aware that resampling wont increase your data quality, and the "better" way would be do downsample the 1/3 arc second areas to 13 arc seconds.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: For some use cases it is best to have the low-resolution images on the bottom layer and high-resolution images on a top layer. Then user can get the best available resolution from any location without resampling the native datasets. Details depend very much on the use case and software. A server like MapServer can do that on-the-fly.